# How to run different code depends on the way python script is runned from the terminal or in an IDE?

Tags: python, terminal, argparse, configparser

Ok, so lets say I have this part of the code (it is not perfect). I want this scenario - I am detecting the cloud name ones as an argument in `__init__` so all other modules and scripts will run on that cloud, or if I want to run the specific python file from the terminal I can detect the cloud on which I want it to be runned like this `python my_script.py cloud1` What would be the best way to do this? 
The following script does work when I am running it from the terminal with the argument, but if not it gives this error

```
usage: To check what is the cloud name config_parser.py: error: too few arguments'
```

here is a code

```
class CredentialsCP:

def __init__(self, cloud_name=None):
    self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    self.cloud_name = cloud_name
    self.config_file_pass = os.path.expanduser('~/PycharmProjects/ui/config.cfg')
    self.parser = ArgumentParser(usage='To check what is the cloud name')
    self.parser.add_argument('cloud')
    self.args = self.parser.parse_args()
    if self.args:
        self.cloud_name = self.args.cloud
    if self.cloud_name is None:
        self.cloud_name = 'cloud1'
```

I have a function that shows a url of the cloud, that how it is callable

Comment: Are you looking for `sys.argv`? It contains the list of the command line arguments.

Comment: yes @SergeBallesta I thought  to make it with sys.argv, any advises how to do it?

Comment: I do not know how you have structured your script. If you are unsure whether your correctly use it, edit the question with the code that does it and ping me in a comment.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added more info to the question, pls take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArgumentParser` has provision for optional arguments, but the default for positional (non flag) arguments is *required*. Here you could use:

```
self.parser = ArgumentParser(usage='To check what is the cloud name')
self.parser.add_argument('cloud', nargs='?', default='cloud1') # optional argument with default value
self.args = self.parser.parse_args()
self.cloud_name = self.args.cloud
```

Possible improvements:

In this code, `parser` and `args` are member attributes of the class. If they are not used outside the `__init__` method, they could just be locals:

```
self.parser = ArgumentParser(usage='To check what is the cloud name')
parser.add_argument('cloud', nargs='?', default='cloud1') # optional argument with default value
args = .parser.parse_args()
self.cloud_name = args.cloud
```

For only identifying a single optional argument, `argparse` may be overkill. `sys.argv` could be enough:

```
...
self.config_file_pass = os.path.expanduser('~/PycharmProjects/ui/config.cfg')
self.cloud_name = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'cloud1'
```

Comment: It works if I rut it from the file where my class is written, but when I import a module to the different file to use it there it gives an error "NoSectionError: No section:" Do you know what might be a reason and is there any ways to fix it? @SergeBallesta

Comment: @Nadiia: That is a different problem. *NoSectionError: No section* is normaly an error from the configparser module. You could try to check that the .cfg file exists and is accessible...